# Create a dynamic href link inside jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to construct a dynamic href link inside jquery but can't quite get there. I can get `data-id` variable into jquery but I can't figure out how to create a link. Can anyone tell me what I'm going wrong?

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<a href="page.php?page_id=some_page_id>"Read More</a>
```

My html

```
    <a class="fancybox" class="img-responsive" data-id="<?php echo $page_id ?>" id="single_image" href="uploads/<?php echo $file ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>" width="800 ">
<img src="uploads/thumbnails/<?php echo $file ?>" id="<?php echo $file ?>" class="img-responsive" width="190"></a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a#single_image").fancybox({
 afterLoad: function() {
    this.outer.append("<div>" + document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML + "<a href="page.php?page_id=" +$(this.element).data('id') + "Read More</a></div>");
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your accepting my answer, can you upvote also for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `single quote` inside `double` for `'page.php?page_id='`

Replace this jquery code with yours.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a#single_image").fancybox({
     afterLoad: function() {
       this.outer.append("<div>" + document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML + "<a href='page.php?page_id='"+$(this.element).data('id') + "Read More</a></div>");
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't escaping the inner quotes properly. Try this:

```
this.outer.append("<div>" + document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML + "<a href=\"page.php?page_id=\"" +$(this.element).data('id') + "Read More</a></div>");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason I don't get the link appearing. If put in "href" in the string I can see it in the string but as soon as I add "<href" I can't see the string. Any ideas?

Comment: @JulianJ I don't quite understand your example. Would you mind explaining it a bit more clearly? :)

Comment: Well for some reason when I escape the inner quotes like you said I cannot see the outputted link. I experimented and found that if I omitted the '<' from "<href..." I could see an output but as soon as I added the '<' which obviously needs to be there I could not see any output. I can't figure out why that would cause an issue.

Comment: @JulianJ why do you need to add '<' to href? `href` is an attribute of the HTML anchor tag `a`. And '<' is a valid prefix only for html tags not for attributes. This is invalid html: `<href="google.com">` it should be `<a href="google.com">`

Comment: You're quite right. Thank you for spotting that. I got there in the end with:   this.outer.append("<div>" + document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML + "<a href=\"page.php?page_id="+ $(this.element).data('id') + "\">Read More</a></div>");

Comment: @JulianJ I'm glad I could help! :)